# Not able to connect with HTTPS

Tags: java, windows, rest, ssl, https

I have created my Rest API in java and working fine with HTTP. But to secure transportation I have made some changes in server.xml file in eclipse.

First I have created self signed certificate and password for that and mentioned that information in server.xml file like below (All done in windows 7)

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="E:\\SSL\\Certificate.pfx" keystorePass="Certificate123" />
```

But sill am not able to connect webserver with HTTPS.

Can anyone tell me what am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using apache-tomact and it also looks like you have created a keystore in the pkcs12 format.

Try adding the `keystoreType="PKCS12"` attribute to the `connector` element.

You can find additional details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29585_01/PlatformServices.61x/security/src/tsec_ssl_jsp_pkcs12.html).